# Notation in this proof: If $X$ a finite dimensional NVS over $\mathbb C$ then $T$ has a nontrivial inveriant subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, invariant-subspace

**Problem:** Show that if $X$, a normed vector space over $\mathbb C$, has a finite dimension of at least $2$, then $T$ has a nontrivial inveriant subspace.

**Attempt:** Here is a solution I have available to the problem:

An operator on a finite dimensional space can be represented by an $n\times n$ matrix, where $\dim(X)=n$. The eigenvalues to such a matrix are given as the roots of the characteristic polynomial. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, we know that every non-constant, single variable polynomial with complex coefficients has at least one complex root. This means that such a matrix will *always* have at least one non-trivial eigenvalue.

Now, for such a nontrivial eigenvalue $\lambda\in\mathbb C$, there is at least one eigenvector $x\in X:x\neq0$ such that $Tx=\lambda x$, where $T$ is our matrix of interest. **Thus, $\mathbb Cx\subseteq X$ is an invariant subspace.**

To see that $\mathbb Cx$ is nontrivial, consider: since $\dim(X)\ge2$, **we see that $\{0\}\neq\mathbb C x\neq X$ so that $\mathbb Cx$ is not trivial.**

--

I think I get the jist of the proof, but there are two points in the above I am unsure on, both highlighted in bold.

**What is the notation $\mathbb Cx$?** Now I think the claim being demonstrated here is that the set of all eigenvectors of $T$ are an invariant subspace for $T$, because clearly, applying $T$ to the set of eigenvectors gives you scalar multiples of those same vectors, which is a subspace of $X$. On the other hand, I think $\mathbb Cx$ is strictly the application of each complex number to every $x$ in $X$. I don't think this is the same as the set of eigenvectors of $T$, although is this what is being hinted at with this notation? Or am I mistaken?

**I also don't immediately see the claim that $\{0\}\neq\mathbb C x\neq X$** when the dimension of $X$ is greater than one; could somebody provide a clarification of why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to first question:**

Here $\mathbb Cx$ means subspace of $X$ generated by $x$.

i.e. $\mathbb Cx = span \{x\} = \{cx:c \in\mathbb C$}

**Answer to second question:**

As $x \neq 0$ implies dim{$\mathbb Cx$} = $1$ and since dim $X$ is at least 2.

Hence $\{0\}\neq\mathbb C x\neq X$

Comment: Your answer to the second question elucidates it entirely, thanks. As for the first one; is this set meant to represent the set of eigenvectors of $X$? I'm getting a little confused because if $Y\subseteq X$ is an invariant subspace of an operator, say $S$, then $S(Y)\subseteq Y$. But in this case, $T(\mathbb Cx)$ isn't the same as $T(Eig(X)$ where $Eig(X)$ is the set of eigenvectors of $X$?

Comment: Here what you can say is $\mathbb Cx$ is subspace of eigenspace of eigenvalue $\lambda$. Hence invariant subspace.

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames The span of a single eigenvector is not always the entire eigenspace. There may also be other eigenvalues too, so it's inaccurate to say it's the set of eigenvectors of $X$. But, the span of a single eigenvector is always an invariant subspace; the line spanned by the vector always maps to a scaled version of itself!